# Can't resolve a parameter using concat for Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts in arm template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an arm template with Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts inside, which resolves a resource id of one public IP address with a randomly generated name. This IP address is created by the AKS cluster then the Nginx ingress controller being installed. It has a randomly generated name and the only way to properly catch it - using specific tags, assigned to the IP address. To get its resource id another parameter is needed - the name of the resource group, which created automatically by AKS during the cluster creation. The problem here - the deployment script seems like can't correctly resolve this parameter value:

```
"ResourceGroup": {
      "value": "[concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', parameters('Cluster'), '_', resourceGroup().location)]"
    }
```

[incorrect resolving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6OiV.png)

Running of the deployment script fails with the following error:

```
The provided script failed with the following error: System.Management.Automation.ParseException: At line:1 char:38 + . .\userscript.ps1 -RG [concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', para … + ~ Missing expression after ','. At line:1 char:39 + . .\userscript.ps1 -RG [concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', para … + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token 'resourceGroup' in expression or statement. At line:1 char:38 + . .\userscript.ps1 -RG [concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', para … + ~ Missing closing ')' in expression. At line:1 char:53 + . .\userscript.ps1 -RG [concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', para … + ~ An expression was expected after '('. At line:1 char:108 + … Group().name, '_', parameters('Cluster'), '_', resourceGroup().locati … + ~ An expression was expected after '('. At line:1 char:118 + … p().name, '_', parameters('Cluster'), '_', resourceGroup().location)] + ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement. at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(Parser parser, String fileName, String fileContents) at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(ExecutionContext context, String script) at System.Management.Automation.CommandInvocationIntrinsics.NewScriptBlock(String scriptText) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand.ProcessRecord() at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord() at <ScriptBlock>, /mnt/azscripts/azscriptinput/DeploymentScript.ps1: line 220. Please refer to https://aka.ms/DeploymentScriptsTroubleshoot for more deployment script information. (Code: DeploymentScriptError)
```

Following arm and parameter files used:

Template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "ResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Cluster": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "parsingIngressId",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
      "identity": {
        "type": "userAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/xxxxxxxxx": {
          }
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "azPowerShellVersion": "5.0",
        "arguments": "[concat('-RG ', parameters('ResourceGroup'))]",
        "scriptContent": "
         param( [string]$RG)
         Write-Host $RG
         $DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{ }
         $ParsingId = Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $RG | Where-Object { $_.Tag['service'] -like '*ingress-controller*' -and $_.Tag['service']} | Select-Object Id
         $DeploymentScriptOutputs['id'] = $ParsingId.id
          ",
        "timeout": "PT1H",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
        "retentionInterval": "P1D"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "id": {
      "value": "[reference('parsingIngressId').outputs.id]",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Parameters:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "ResourceGroup": {
      "value": "[concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', parameters('Cluster'), '_', resourceGroup().location)]"
    },
    "Location": {
      "value": "resourceGroup().location)"
    },
    "Cluster": {
      "value": "ClusterName"
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea \ suggestion what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to resolve a parameter using the value of another parameter inside the parameters file.

Use a default value for the resource group in the template file and resolve the parameter there.  For example:

```json
  "parameters": {
    "ResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('MC_', resourceGroup().name, '_', parameters('Cluster'), '_', resourceGroup().location)]"
    },
```